# After deploying services I get incorrect public address 

Tags: juju, maas

I deployed wordpress and when I type `juju status` I receive this:

> public-adress: node-001185e6777fe

When I found what is IP adress of this computer I tried type in web browser but I get 502 bad gateway.

After juju status:

```
hsf@ubuntu:~$ juju status
2012-10-05 11:26:49,385 INFO Connecting to environment...
Enter passphrase for key '/home/hsf/.ssh/id_rsa':
2012-10-05 11:26:51,905 INFO Connected to environment.
machines:
  0:
    agent-state: running
    dns-name: node-00127968a7be.local
    instance-id: /MAAS/api/1.0/nodes/node-ab7c5eb6-0e08-11e2-bb37-001185e67955/
    instance-state: unknown
  1:
    agent-state: running
    dns-name: node-001185e677fe
    instance-id: /MAAS/api/1.0/nodes/node-82beae92-0e09-11e2-a134-001185e67955/
    instance-state: unknown
  2:
    agent-state: running
    dns-name: node-001185e6772b.local
    instance-id: /MAAS/api/1.0/nodes/node-5c21dc18-0e0a-11e2-a134-001185e67955/
    instance-state: unknown
services:
  wordpress:
    charm: cs:precise/wordpress-9
    exposed: true
    relations:
      loadbalancer:
      - wordpress
    units:
      wordpress/2:
        agent-state: started
        machine: 1
        open-ports: []
        public-address: node-001185e677fe.localdomain
2012-10-05 11:26:52,459 INFO 'status' command finished successfully
hsf@ubuntu:~$
```

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the names of your nodes, you're using mDNS so I'd recommend renaming your node 'node-001185e677fe' into 'node-001185e677fe.local'.

Comment: I want IP adresses.